# Xamarin forms twoway binding not firing after initial load

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, viewmodel

I have a problem which has taken hours upon hours of my time.  I am sure I am missing something obvious.  I have reproduced the issue on a simplified form which uses just 1 button and 1 label.  Label correctly sets to initial value.  Upon button click I am trying to change the label text.  From David to Terry.

Command button is firing, setter is getting called, onPropertyChange is getting called.  Interestingly after initial debug the get'er is not fired again.  (Checked all obvious things, property is public and a property, it is named correctly, specified TwoWay)

...

```
//--- View Model code ---//
public class TestBindingVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string profileName;

    public ICommand ChangeTextCommand { get; }

    public TestBindingVM()
    {
        ProfileName = "David";
        ChangeTextCommand = new Command(UpdateTextCommandAction);
    }

    public void UpdateTextCommandAction()
    {
        ProfileName = "Terry";
    }


    public string ProfileName
    {
        get => profileName;
        set
        {
            profileName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProfileName");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyChangedCallback = PropertyChanged;
        propertyChangedCallback?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
// ---------------------
// Complete XAML Layout :
//----------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="TrackManager.Views.TestBindingPage">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Path=ProfileName}"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Button Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="Change Text"
                    Command="{Binding ChangeTextCommand}"
                    TextColor="White"
                    />
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>

///----------------------------------------------//
// The page code, creating the bindingcontext    //
///----------------------------------------------//
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class TestBindingPage : ContentPage
{
    public ViewModels.TestBindingVM vm = new ViewModels.TestBindingVM();

    public TestBindingPage ()
    {
        this.BindingContext = vm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

...

This is similar to this post, which did not get a complete answer.  Perhaps due to missing code:

[Two way binding Not working In Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669469/two-way-binding-not-working-in-xamarin-forms)

It is just so strange that the value "David" is shown on loading.  Which shows binding is close to working.

Help appreciated.

Comment: why are you using TwoWay binding with a Label?  TwoWay only makes sense if the control allows the user to interact with it, like an Entry or Picker.  A Label is not interactive.

Comment: It is set to twoWay so that the code behind can change the text as needed.  Also tried with and without the twoWay :-(

Comment: Data --> UI is one way.  You don't need to specify that, a Label control will default to that binding.  Try just `Text="{Binding ProfileName}"`

Comment: Thanks.  Just tried again when I saw your comment.  Exactly same behavior.  This is going to be something so dumb when it is found.

Comment: no idea.  I've used binding thousands of times in Forms projects without a problem.  You might want to double check your implementation of INPC vs one of the Microsoft docs, but at a glance it appears correct to me.

Comment: Is there anything in the surrounding XAML that could interfere/reset the BindingContext?  Are there any other methods implemented on TestBindingPage?

Comment: The snippet is basically it.  I just left off the usual preamble stuff like the content page definition and the usings.  I removed all other stuff to simplify the issue.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: not unless you are overriding the binding context in the XAML.  If you want to share the code I can take a quick look

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I edited the original to show the complete XAML.  I don't think much suspicious there, but appreciate the extra eyes!

Comment: I copy & pasted your code into a sample project, and the button changed the label text as expected on button click on UWP and Android. What platform are you seeing this on? What version of Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time to do that!  I did have a few packages which had updates required.  I updated them all.  Xamarin.Forms is now 4.0.0.425677.  Everything else showing as up to date.  I did have to downgrade Android support to make some Google Auth work.  For kicks I will do as you did and create a new X.form app and just copy paste this code in.  Thanks again.

Comment: Oh my gosh, the code I copied from this post worked exactly as supposed to.  Now it would be nice to know why.  DavidS thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: When debugging using the clean new app, there is a difference, the PropertyChanged is always null on the regular app but it set to something in the new app.

Comment: Just for the record, I found the issue.  For some reason there was a local, empty interface of INPC.  I guess when using the refactor function I clicked implement interface rather than add 'using'.  DavidS / Jason, thank you so much for helping out, you guys deserve medals.  Anybody know how I close this thread so it doesn't waste other people's time?

Comment: If you have solution, post your solution to answer, and mark it after two days, so it will help others who have similar issue. If you did not have solution, delete this case , it will be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I found the issue.  For some reason there was a local, empty interface of INPC.  I guess when using the refactor function I clicked implement interface rather than add 'using'.  Therefore when the INPC isn't doing what it clearly should, check you are using the actual INPC not some stub :-)